# extracting and printing an html element by it's class using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

what i want to do is to get an element with its class name and show it as a actual html element not it nodes or its inner data

here is my code

```
$html = file_get_contents("www.site.com");
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$element = $dom->getElementById('myid');
$string = $element->C14N();
```

here is how i do it using ID but i want to now if there is a way to do this using class apparently there is no getElementByClass method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward method in php dom to do this. You will have to walk all the elements and check if their class attribute contains the class name you need...

```
$html = file_get_contents("www.site.com");
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element) {
    if (strpos($element->getAttribute('class'), 'yourClassNameHere') !== false) {
        $string = $element->C14N();
    }
}
```

You can also use [DOMXpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php):

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query("*/div[@class='yourClassNameHere']") as $element) {
    $string = $element->C14N();
}
```

Comment: thanx problem with xpath is i cant use C14N method on it's result

Comment: DOMXpath::query() returns DOMNodeList, so you have to walk it too. Or if you are sure that it is going to return one element, or don't care about the other elements, you cat just do this: $xpath->query("...")->item(0)->C14N();

Comment: thank you . i have one last question i'm selecting an element which contains non-ascii / none latin characters  using DOMDocument but when i printout the element it's characters are all messed up . does DOMDocument have problem with multi byte characters ? and if yes is there a method to deal with this problem ?

Comment: When DOMDocument loads xml it expects it to be either in encoding specified by the declaration, or in php internal encoding. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php and especially php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php. There are many examples there.